# i got an error while creating maven project in eclipse neon on ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, maven

Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1
Missing org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1